# Angularjs 2 @viewChild is not working

Tags: angular, angularjs-components

New to angularjs 2, I need to use @viewChild but it throws error as **'Cannot read property 'rotateLeft' of undefined'**.
**parent :**

```
<div><pdfReader [imageUrl]="imgsource" *ngIf="holeDocument.ext == 'pdf'"></pdfReader></div>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component ,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {PdfReader} from "../../shared/pdfreader/pdfReader";
@Component({
selector: 'docView',
templateUrl: 'docView.html',
styleUrls : ["docView.less"]
})  
export class DocViewComponent{
@ViewChild('PdfReader') public pdfReader: PdfReader;
constructor(){}
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.imageRotate();
}             
imageRotate(){ 
this.pdfReader.rotateLeft();
}}
```

**Child :**

```
@Component({
selector: 'pdfReader',
templateUrl: 'pdfReader.html'
})
export class PdfReader{
 @Input() imageUrl : any;
 rotateLeft(){
        console.log('rotateLeft called');
        this.rotationAngel -= 90;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see in your question how you use `@ViewChild()`. Don't you think this would be the most important part of your question?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer @ViewChild('PdfReader') public pdfReader: PdfReader; also edited.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.pdfReader);` in `ngAfterViewInit()` print? Is the HTML in your question part of the components template. Please add the `@Component()` decorators and the components class name to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the component type to query, then the quotes are redundant

```
@ViewChild(PdfReader) public pdfReader: PdfReader;
```

If you use a string as query there needs to be a matching template variable

```
<div><pdfReader #PdfReader [imageUrl]="imgsource" *ngIf="holeDocument.ext == 'pdf'"></pdfReader></div>
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Answer (score 1):

```
 *ngIf="holeDocument.ext == 'pdf'"
```

*ngIf is doing the trick. element is not rendered until that condition has met.

use [hidden] instead.

```
<pdfReader [imageUrl]="imgsource" [hidden]="holeDocument.ext != 'pdf'"></pdfReader>
```